# How to send notification to all controllers in iOS

Tags: ios, web-services, http-headers, nsnotification

I have an instance of `NSObject` that calls all web services by taking parameters. I want to catch `404 HTTP Error` and take all controllers to a specific one.
Is there any way except `observe notification` in all of them?
Can AppDelegate help in this way?

Thanks guys!

Comment: I would suggest to Create a sub class of `UIViewController` and implement it in this subclass, then inherit all of your `ViewControllers` from that `UIViewController` subclass

Comment: That was true @SyedAliSalman. How can I mark this as true?

Comment: It was just a comment bro

Comment: I am copying it to answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to Create a sub class of `UIViewController` and implement it in this subclass, then inherit all of your `ViewControllers` from that `UIViewController` subclass